# How can I create requested image files when file not found?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

For example, if I have a file `http://site.com/images/bird.jpg`

When I go `http://site.com/images/bird-200px-width.jpg` the server will say "file not found".

When the server determines the file is not found, is there a way to check the /images/ directory to see if an image with the first part of the title ("bird.jpg"), and if it exists, automatically resize and generate an image with the requested filename instead of saying "file not found"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. As you asked a theoretical question, my answer will be theoretical too. Hope it's useful to you:

1. You could check if the file **does NOT exist** with a rewrite cond
   in .htaccess (**[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)**)
2. If the file doesn't exist, check again if the other file **does
   exist** (again a rewrite cond that looks for e.g. `bird(.*)`.jpg
   where `(.*)` is your wildcard)
3. Now if that file exists point to e.g. a php file that processes the
   image and shows it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (specifically `RedirectCond` [twice]) to detect the absence of the thumbnail and rewrite to a script that generates and outputs the image.